# How to create SSDT project from existing database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have an existing SQL database and I need to add an SSDT project to the project I am working on. 
What would the correct way to add the tables and stored procs from the existing database to an SSDT project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Schema Compare with your existing database to populate your SSDT project.  I think you will find that it is really rather simple.

Schema Compare uses two connections (connection strings) to compare two different databases, or in your case one connection string to connect to the existing database (source) and then you choose your database project project as the other (target).

Comment: I'm going to give that a shot

Answer (score 2):

I think this covers all the options:

https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/HOWTO-Get-An-Existing-Schema-Into-SSDT

Good luck, common issues when you start are references and code that doesn't actually run (procs reference dropped table etc) - for references if you use anything in msdn or master or any sys.* objects add a reference to the dacpacs for non working code, check a baseline into source control and then delete it :)

Ed